# Each word divided on character in array

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with reading a txt file in Java. I have a File.txt (there is something like this:

```
Lalala
Java
C++
```

I want to 'convert' it into an array (for example for `tab[0][0]` will be `L`, then `tab[0][1]` will be `a`, etc.).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are we supposed to make your homework? What have you tried? Tip, use a FileReader, to create an InputStream> You can read lines from there.

Comment: Have you managed to read the file? Start by successfully reading the lines

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: You say you "have a problem" - what *is* the problem?  What have you tried, and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `String`, you can convert it into an array of single characters by calling `String.toCharArray();`

First, split the String up into individual words...

```
String myExample = "Lalala Java C++";
String[] lines = myExample.split(" ");
```

Then split the individual lines into characters...

```
String myFirstLine = lines[0];
char[] letters = myFirstLine.toCharArray();
```

If you need it in a 2D array, you could then do something like this (this is a full example)...

```
String myExample = "Lalala Java C++";
String[] lines = myExample.split(" ");

char[][] myArray = new char[lines.length][0];
for (int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    myArray[i] = lines[i].toCharArray();
}
```

This will assign the letters of line 1 to `myArray[0][0]`, `myArray[0][1]`, etc, and the letters of line 2 to `myArray[1][0]`, `myArray[1][1]`, etc, as you requested.

Comment: this converts everything in 1 single char array, he needs a char 2d array

Comment: Yeah I didn't quite understand that requirement at first, but I think I know what they're asking now.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a bidimensional array, the problem is that the width of the array need to be the length of the bigger word. I think is not a good practice.

Maybe if you create a list of arrays, it can be better:

```
List<char[]> arrays = new ArrayList<char[]>();

String[] words = fullText.split(" "); //or split("\\s+") if the text contains many lines  or many spaces between the words

for(String word: words){
   char[] charsOfWord = word.toCharArray();
   arrays.add(charsOfWord);
}
```

This way, to access the frist character in the first word:

```
System.out.println(arrays.get(0)[0]);
```